# Problems while upgrading solution from PHP 5.6 to 7.1

Tags: php, mysql, php-7

Im a beginner but have managed to mage a booking site for a client that is running fine on a server with mysql 5.7.21 and php 5.6.

But now I have to move the site to a server thats running php 7.1

I've managed to duplicate the database on the new server and I can connect to it - but now I have a lot of code that don't work (used mysql commands).

I have the following code where I've substituted "mysql" with "mysqli" and a newer closing db command but its not working - code only generate the top part of the table with the headings. - Could somebody come to my rescue :) ?

**oversigt.php:**

```
<?php
echo "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css.css' />";
echo '<h2>Reserve a spot</h2>';
echo '<a href="login.php" class="text_black">Administration</a><br /><br />';



    include('dbConfig.php');



if ($dbConnected) {

$sqli = "SELECT ";
$sqli .= "SUM(Company_Bookings.Spots) as SUMSPOT, Company_Trips.ID, Company_Bookings.FK_ID, Company_Trips.MaxSpots, ";
$sqli .= "Company_Trips.Tripnr, Company_Trips.StartDate, Company_Trips.EndDate, Company_Trips.StartLocation, ";
$sqli .= "Company_Trips.DestinationDK, Company_Trips.PricePerSpot ";
$sqli .= "FROM Company_Trips ";
$sqli .= "LEFT JOIN Company_Bookings on Company_Bookings.FK_ID = Company_Trips.ID WHERE Company_Trips.EndDate >= NOW() AND Company_Trips.EndDate < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 YEAR) ";
$sqli .= "GROUP BY Company_Trips.ID, Company_Bookings.FK_ID ORDER BY Company_Trips.StartDate ASC ";

$sqli_Query = mysqli_query($sqli);

$tdOdd = 'style = "background-color: #FFFFFF;"';
$tdEven = 'style = "background-color: #ced4ee;"';

echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>Trip nr</th>";
        echo "<th>Days</th>";
        echo "<th>Start date</th>";
        echo "<th>End date</th>";
        echo "<th>Departure place</th>";
        echo "<th>Destination</th>";
        echo "<th>Price per day</th>";
        echo "<th>Max spots</th>";
        echo "<th>Available spots</th>";
       echo "<th>&nbsp;</th>";

    echo "</tr>";

$indx = 1;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqli_Query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $SUMSPOTS = $row['SUMSPOT'];
    $SpotsLeft = $row['MaxSpots'] - $SUMSPOTS;
    $Tripnr = $row['Tripnr'];
    $StartDate = $row['StartDate'];
    $EndDate = $row['EndDate'];
    $StartLocation = $row['StartLocation'];
    $DestinationDK = $row['DestinationDK'];
    $PricePerSpot = $row['PricePerSpot'];
    $MaxSpots = $row['MaxSpots'];
    $StartDate1 = strtotime($row['StartDate']);
    $EndDate1 = strtotime($row['EndDate']);
     $Datediff = $EndDate1 - $StartDate1;
     $Datediff2 = ceil($Datediff / (60 * 60 * 24));

    if (($indx % 2) == 1) {$rowClass = $tdOdd; } else { $rowClass = $tdEven; }

    echo "<tr ".$rowClass.">";

        echo "<td>".$Tripnr."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$Datediff2."</td>";
        echo "<td>".date('D d/m/Y', strtotime($StartDate))."</td>";
        echo "<td>".date('D d/m/Y', strtotime($EndDate))."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$StartLocation."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$DestinationDK."</td>";
        echo "<td>&euro; ".$PricePerSpot."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$MaxSpots."</td>";


    //  if $result = ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){};
        echo "<td>".$SpotsLeft."</td>";

 if ($SpotsLeft < 1){
echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
 } else {
echo "<td><a href='createBooking.php?ID=".$row['ID']."&IDD=".$SpotsLeft."'>Book</a></td>";
 }

    echo "</tr>";

    $indx++;

 }

echo "</table>";

}
mysqli_close($sqli_Query);

?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately there is more to it than changing `mysql_` to `mysqli_` You are going to have to look at the manual. The parameters required by the `mysqli_` API are different to the `mysql_` API

Comment: [PHP Manual, available in many languages](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: Thank you but Ive already got a copyist up and runnung - I was hoping for a brilliant mind to help me make a few changes to fix it. I learned this obsolete coding from Udemy.com and I am trying to get up to speed - but I don't know when I will be good enough to fix the problems and my client is on my back /-)

Comment: You will have to debug your code. One of the ways to do it is checking for errors f.e. https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_error.asp If that doesn't show you the error. You can go through your code and check if variables contains what is expected. F.E. `var_dump($row); exit();` And so on

Comment: I for one have no idea what a copyist is? And please remember whats Urgent to you is not necessarily urgent to us

Comment: Is this all the code database access code for this web site?

Comment: Yes sorry - couldn't change my comment.

Comment: copyist = copy site

Comment: I already have this site up and running fine - but on the new server running PHP 7.1 it is not running. I already know the mysql commands are obsolete and I have tried to replace them with new ones - but apparently something is broken.

Comment: I was thinking it was only a few commands That needs to be updated/changed

Comment: This is just one page (inside a Muse mockup) - but If I can get this page up and running - I could probably fix the other 15 or so files.

Comment: dbConfig.php contains this code: 
<?php

$hostname = '';
$username = '';
$password = '';
$database = '';
$dbConnected = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database);

if(!$dbConnected){
   die('Could not connect: '.mysqli_connect_error());
}

?>

Comment: I just removed the specific data

Comment: Fixed the issue